# Display only the nearest element with the given class

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the code so that when I click on the reply-img, only the following element with the reply-form class is displayed, but the others are not displayed at the same time.

I have several elements with the reply-img class and I always want to display the closest element with the reply-form class

HTML blade.php

```
<div class="comments-form">
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
    
    <div class="comments">
       ...
                            
       <div class="reply-img">
           <img src="{{asset('img/react.svg')}}" alt="">
       </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'</form>
    
    @endforeach
...
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
        // Get all image elements
        var images = document.querySelectorAll(".reply-img");
    
        // Attach a click event listener to each image
        images.forEach(function(image) {
            image.addEventListener("click", function() {
                // Show all forms
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".reply-form");
                forms.forEach(function(form) {
                    form.style.display = "block";
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the image element's `.parentElement` twice to navigate up the tree to the `<div class="comments">`. Then use `.nextElementSibling` to get to the `form` element.

Like this:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const form = img.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
console.log(form.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="comments">
  <div class="reply-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
</div>
<form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'>blah</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it cleaner to toggle a class on the comments to indicate the active comment. Then we can handle the forms with CSS.

Here's an example of that:

```js
const comments = document.querySelectorAll('.comments');

document.querySelectorAll('.reply-img').forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', function() {
  comments.forEach(x => x.classList.remove('active-comment'));
  this.parentElement.classList.add('active-comment');
}))
```

```css
.reply-form {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.comments:not(.active-comment)+.reply-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-form">

  <div class="comments">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  ...
</div>
```

This can also be done without JavaScript, just CSS.
By adding the `tabindex` attribute to the comments, the comments get a focus state. Now we can use the focus state to toggle the display of the forms.

Note that in this case clicking on the comment will cause the form to display, not only clicking on the image.

```css
.reply-form {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.comments:not(:focus)+.reply-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-form">

  <div class="comments" tabindex="0">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  <div class="comments" tabindex="0">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  <div class="comments" tabindex="0">
    <div class="reply-img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class='login-form mmm ml-x reply-form'></form>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to change your function so that it shows only the next form and not all of them:

```
images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let ele = image.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    while(ele){
      if(ele.matches('.reply-form')){
        ele.style.display = "block";
        return;
      }
      ele = ele.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
});
```